# HTACCESS + PHP Headers to route an image download

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, routes

I am working on a basic API/REST setup for a personal project, and to help me to understand better API/REST building.

My Goals:

1. POST image to my API (completed)
2. Compress it (completed)
3. Download it back ***(stuck)***

On the response back, it should just be JSON (with file params), right?

The next question, in similar format, I want to have a url like:
https://example.com/api/download/image.png

And it would serve up JSON (with the file params of "image.png") as well. This would enable me to change the file path down the road, but the URL would stay the same.

Although what the server is responding with is this:

[image]

My HTACCESS, is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^api/download/(.*)$ api.php?download=true&image=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php?image=$1 [L,QSA]
```

A snippet of the code for 'download' method

```
if(!empty($_GET['image']) && isset($_GET['download']) && ($_GET['download'] === 'true') ) {
    echo "temp/".$_GET['image'];
    if(file_exists("temp/".$_GET['image'])) {
        header($protocol." 200 OK");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $download['download'] = "https://example.com/newtemppath/".$_GET['image'];
        echo json_encode($download);

    } else {
        header($protocol." 404 Not Found");
    }
}
```

Hope this is clear, looking for any direction here, Thanks!

Comment: *"looking for any direction here"* - If you're looking for boolean true, then this `$_GET['download'] === 'true'` will fail, since it's checking for a string equivalent. If you're looking for boolean, remove the quotes for it `$_GET['download'] === true`.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` anything from that?

Comment: I believe, $_GET['download'] === 'true', will be a string from the URL, not boolean here.

Comment: Yeah I have error reporting on, no errors. The server seems to be trying to look for /api/download/image.png as an actual IMAGE, but I need to route it first to the proper spot, and serve JSON, NOT the image.....